# Can I use a Dictionary to create a menu in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, types, menu

I want to build a menu in Python (using the latest version). For example:

```
menu_options = {
    1: {'Option 1', 'regular'},
    2: {'Option 2',  'regular'},
    3: {'Option 3', 'admin'}
}
```

I will have 2 types of users, regular and admin. So when I print this menu, I will check what type is my user, and then either print all three options for admin... or just 1 and 2 for regular users.

```
def print_menu(user_type):
    for key in menu_options.keys():
        item, level = menu_options[key]
        if (user_type == 'admin'):
            print(key, '--', item)
        elif (level == 'regular'):
            print(key, '--', item)
```

So apparently the dictionaries are kind of magic, and I won't get the values in the same order that I used to create the dictionary...

```
1 -- Option 1
2 -- Option 2
3 -- Option 3
```

Can any other data type work better for me? I have seen `OrderedDict` in the documentation, but I'm not sure if it's just a matter of ordering the elements...

Comment: The structure of your dictionary looks wrong. Why are the values in themselves unordered sets? Wouldn't tuples or lists make more sense? Or, why would you need to store "Option 1" if the only way of getting it is using 1? That seems to be something you shouldn't store at all!

Comment: Why do you want to use a dictionary? Why not use any other data structure like a list or a tuple?

Answer (score 3):

This is not that dictionaries are magic. You're just using an inappropriate data type for the values stored in the dictionary.

Use lists or tuples instead of sets.

Other than that, a dictionary is not what you need if you want to just enumerate elements by their position. A list of a tuple can already do that.

Comment: My real menu is not actually this… I wrote option 1 just to simplify, my mistake.

Comment: No the point here is that if you just want to do `menu[2]`, then you don't need a dict at all. You access elements of lists and tuples by their position anyways.